# Using a varibale outside of the event listener block

Tags: javascript, variables, global, event-listener

I have been having difficulty accessing the variables populated within an eventlistener which is used to obtain the results from a php query.  I tried a number of different ideas but I have been unsuccessful. Any help would be appreciated

```
{ 
    var longnew = -64.1;
    var latnew = 44.52;
    var trigger = 10;
    var longs = 0;
    var lats = 0;
     
    query.addEventListener("submit", (event) =>{}) 
    onsubmit = (event) => {
        let long = "<?php echo"$long"?>";
        let lat = "<?php echo"$lat"?>";
        longs = parseFloat(long);
        lats = parseFloat(lat);
        trigger = 1;

        if (trigger == 1){ //check variables
            alert('Updated Extent:'+ longs + ', ' + lats + ', ' + trigger); // this reports the old   search values check order of php sqlite query
        }
    }
    
    if(trigger == 1) { //check to see if trigger isbeing read
        alert('Updated Extent:'+ longs + ', ' + lats + ', ' + trigger); // this reports the old search values check order of php sqlite query
        longnew = longs;
        latnew = lats;
    }
      
    alert('Default or Updated Extent (*new): '+longnew + ', ' +latnew + ', ' +trigger);
       
}
```

I assumed by declaring the variables longs and lats at the start of the block that they could be populated and accessible.  I also tried declaring a function but it also did not work.

Comment: java or javascript?

Comment: You never call the `onsubmit` function. Did you mean to use `query.addEventListener("submit", onsubmit);`?

Comment: Your first `if (trigger == 1)` will always succeed, because you just assigned the variable on the previous line. The second will never succeed, because it doesn't wait until after the event is triggered.

Comment: If you assign a variable inside an event listener, the new value isn't available until after the event occurs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Comment: Thank you for the response the code is part of a web page that: 1) loads a web page, includes a search bar to lookup a new set of coordinates.      2) when it loads, it defaults to -64.1, 44.52, as expected since trigger is not 1 has not yet been set by the search. 3) when a successful query is completed, the alert based on trigger ==1 runs correctly as expected.  However, the variables are not updated outside of the query.addEventListener.

Comment: As it turns out, the variables were being dropped during a refresh and therefore I used sessionStorage.SetItem() and sessionStorage.getItem to retrieve them. 
This solved the issue.
Thanks for the responses.